# find(list) returns several blank options, find(all) returns correct data but formatted with {

Tags: cakephp-3.0

**AvadiariesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('AlumnesGrups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'alumnes_grup_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
```

**AlumnesGrupsTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Alumnes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'alumne_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Grups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'grup_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

**Why is this in AvadiariesController.php:**

```
 public function add()
    {
    $avadiary = $this->Avadiaries->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $avadiary = $this->Avadiaries->patchEntity($avadiary, $this->request->data);
            $avadiary->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if ($this->Avadiaries->save($avadiary)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The avadiary has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The avadiary could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    $alumnesGrups = $this->Avadiaries->AlumnesGrups->find('all', [
    'fields' => ['Alumnes.name'], 
    'contain' =>['Alumnes', 'Grups'], 
    'conditions' => ['Grups.id =' => 1], 
    'order' => ['Alumnes.name' => 'ASC']
    ]);
$this->set(compact('avadiary', 'alumnesGrups'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['avadiary']);
    }
```

returning correct data but formatted like this:

{"Alumnes":{"name":"Angela Smith"}}?

How can I just get Angela Smith? If I change find(all) to find(list), the selectbox is populated with several blank options.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find('list')` and use `valueField` for the field you want to show and `keyField` for its value:

```
$alumnesGrups = $this->Avadiaries->AlumnesGrups->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'alumne.name', 
    'valueField' => 'alumne.name'])
->contain(['Alumnes', 'Grups']) 
->where(['Grups.id =' => 1]) 
->order(['Alumnes.name' => 'ASC']);
```

Check:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

Comment: Thank you very much but I already tried this and values keep being in blank. I also checked if encoding was OK in datasources section from app.php.

Comment: I am now trying with Hash::extract, but I get a fatal error Class Hash not found.

Comment: please explain the code you used when you tried `find('list')`

Comment: I managed to code it exactly like you did before you suggested it. I have tried your code again and got the same blank results.

Comment: Yes, there was an error: the name of the model must be singular lower case in valueField and keyField. See my edit (mind that I don't know if the inflection is right in your language)

Comment: Working! Yay! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thing is...I cannot save data if this is applied in a selectbox for adding data :/ Any idea?

Comment: Usually the keyfield is the id of the model and not the name but i imagined you had your reason to fo that

Comment: But if I replace `'keyField' => 'alumne.name'` by `'keyField' => 'alumnesgrup.id'`...then I get a **'This value does not exist'** error.

Comment: I added extra code in my initial question as it may be clarifying :)

Comment: Dont know what informazioni you want to save but it is either alumne.id or alumne_grup.id

Comment: There's a difference between what I should see and what I should save. I should store in Avadiaries.alumnegrup_id an ID from AlumnesGrups.id but instead of seeing a list of IDs, I should see the name related to it, which is in Alumnes.name.